# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la dirección dirección de url de un WebView dependiendo del botón al que se la haya dado click?

Tags: java, android-studio, activity

Tengo varias `activitys`, en una de ellas se encuentra un menú con diferentes botones y en las otras `activitys` las cuales son del tipo `tabbed`, existen 3 `fragments` y en cada uno de estos `fragments` hay un `WebView`, hasta ahora he hecho que cada botón del menú me lleve a una `activity` diferente, pero necesito saber si se puede hacer que dependiendo del botón del menú que se haya oprimido se modifique la **url** de los `WebView, para de esta forma no utilizar una`activity`por cada`WebView` y así ahorrar espacio.

**Código del menú:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity




    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
LinearLayout contProgs;
ScrollView testWeb;
Button btnInformatica, btnBiologia, btnQuimica, btnMatematicas, btnFisica;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    };

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);




    contProgs=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.contProgs);

    btnInformatica=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_informatica);
    btnBiologia=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_biologia);
    btnQuimica=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_quimica);
    btnMatematicas=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_matematicas);
    btnFisica=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_fisica);



    btnInformatica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Intent InformaticiActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InformaticaActivity.class);
            startActivity(InformaticiActivity);
       }
    });

    btnBiologia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent BologiiActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BiologiaActivity.class);
            startActivity(BologiiActivity);
        }
    });

    btnQuimica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent QuimiActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, QuimicaActivity.class);
            startActivity(QuimiActivity);
        }
    });

    btnMatematicas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent MaterActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MatematicasActivity.class);
            startActivity(MaterActivity);
        }
    });

    btnMatematicas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent MaterActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MatematicasActivity.class);
            startActivity(MaterActivity);
        }
    });

    btnFisica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent FisisActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FisicaActivity.class);
            startActivity(FisisActivity);
        }
    });




}
```

**Código de la `tabbed activity`:**

```
public class InformaticaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

Button btn1;
WebView wView;


private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_informatica);






    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);





        }

// Métodos de la interfaz ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

// Métodos de la interfaz ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}




public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {



    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment tabFragment = null;

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                tabFragment = new FInformatica1();
                break;
            case 1:
                tabFragment = new Finformatica2();
                break;
            case 2:
                tabFragment = new Finforamtica3();
                break;
        }
        return tabFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 2 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        String section = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                section = "Aspectos generales";
                break;
            case 1:
                section = "Talento humano";
                break;
            case 2:
                section = "Plan de estudios";
                break;
        }
        return section;
    }
}
}
```

**Código de un `fragment`:**

```
public class FInformatica1 extends Fragment {

Button btn1;
WebView wView;
TextView textView2;

ZoomControls zoomIt;

public FInformatica1() {
    // Required empty public constructor


}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);






}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_finformatica1, container, false);

    String url = "file:///android_asset/nitro/informatica/indexInformatica.html";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    view.loadUrl(url);







    return  rootView;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo tienes que hacer una actividad que tenga un navegador, y pasarle la url que tiene que abrir mediante el mismo intento:

[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) permite adjuntarle datos adicionales, llamados **extras**, mediante la función `intent.putExtra("nombre_del_extra", "Cadena que se desea pasar")`,  que luego pueden ser recibidos en la otra actividad mediante `intent.getStringExtra("nombre_del_extra")`, por ejemplo:

**Actividad 1, envias los datos:**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), WVClass.class);
  intent.putExtra("url", "http://google.com");
  startActivity(intent);
```

**Actividad 2, recibes los datos:**

```
  String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

Simple, así como pasas la url, puedes pasar el título de la actividad, etc. Sería bueno que leyeras la [documentación de Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) en Android Developers, y veas todo lo que se puede pasar por los extras, incluyendo los Serializables.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, el problema es que eso me sirve para una actividad normal, pero para pasar el intent al interior del fragment no se puede de esa forma, he intentado con getActivity, pero tampoco me da.

Comment: Ya entiendo, a modo de chapucería puedes usar una actividad normal, con pestañas hechas por Layout, como simulando las pestañas, y que cuando el usuario las oprima el WebView cambie de url.